# Is the rsync block compression dictionary reset for each file?

Tags: rsync, compression

Does `rsync -z` compress blocks of each file without regard to the previous file, or is the compression dictionary reset for each file so that it is handled independently?

As an example, consider a compressible file `one.txt` and its identical copy being transferred to a remote server, where neither file yet exists:

```
cp -p one.txt two.txt
rsync -az one.txt two.txt remote:
```

Does the `zlib` compression layer treat `one.txt` and `two.txt` independently, or is the data transfer at that level simply a continuous stream, so it will have learned a useful compression dictionary for `one.txt` that it can apply to `two.txt`?

Alternatively, have I completely misunderstood the `zlib` compression algorithm, such that (for example) the dictionary is always reset for each new block?

I've tried looking at the `rsync` debug output `rsync -avvvvz --debug=IO1,IO2,IO3,IO4 --msgs2stderr` but I can't see anything that specifically relates to the compression layer.

<sub>(This is following up a [comment thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/678422/compress-whole-directory-with-rsync-and-upload-to-remote/678428?noredirect=1#comment1291182_678428) on an answer of mine on ServerFault.)</sub>

Comment: The [DEFLATE algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) used in `zlib` supplies a Huffman tree (which may be what you call "dictionary") with _each_ compressed block. Unless I'm misunderstanding the algorithm (I haven't read the `zlib` sources), this would mean that each block of data is compressed individually and that the data in one file is not relevant to the compression of the data in the next file.  Not turning this into an answer as I'm not certain about the technical details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rsync` uses compression in [`token.c`](https://download.samba.org/pub/unpacked/rsync/token.c), and seemingly only there. It maintains deflate stream state in the `tx_strm` variable, and resets the stream state in `send_deflated_token` if the previous token is -1:

```c
        if (last_token == -1) {
                /* initialization */
                if (!init_done) {
                        tx_strm.next_in = NULL;
                        tx_strm.zalloc = NULL;
                        tx_strm.zfree = NULL;
                        if (deflateInit2(&tx_strm, compression_level,
                                         Z_DEFLATED, -15, 8,
                                         Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY) != Z_OK) {
                                rprintf(FERROR, "compression init failed\n");
                                exit_cleanup(RERR_PROTOCOL);
                        }
                        if ((obuf = new_array(char, OBUF_SIZE)) == NULL)
                                out_of_memory("send_deflated_token");
                        init_done = 1;
                } else
                        deflateReset(&tx_strm);
```

This is used from [`match.c`](https://download.samba.org/pub/unpacked/rsync/match.c), *via* the `match` function, used by `hash_search` and `match_sums`. These functions always ensure that they finish their processing with a call which leaves `last_token` set to -1, so that the next call will reset the deflate stream. All this is done file-by-file, so the deflate stream is always reset at the start of each file.

This means that the block compression dictionary is guaranteed to be reset for each file; it might be reset more often.

If `rsync` were to use data from previous files, it might be more interesting to extend its hash handling across files.

You can verify all this experimentally by syncing multiple copies of compressible files, as you suggest; the stats always show that the transferred size is equal to the compressed size of a single file, multiplied by the number of copies, so there is no de-duplication of one kind or another across files.

Comment: I have mused about trying to building some sort of session-wide block-based transfer tool, knowing that often my directory trees do have lots of duplicates (but not files I can simply hardlink). The memory usage would be, er, _interesting_, though.

Comment: Borg, Restic and other backup tools perform backup-wide deduplication without too much overhead...